# javascript is not sending data through php code

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, json

Hi i have a requirement where i need to execute mysql queries once user will confirm Ok from confirmation box.In my case what ever data i am passing to insert_details.php is not working. one more thing i would like to bring to your notice that i need to send data to different script and navigate it to different page.kindly suggest where is the problem?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            var r=confirm("This email address already exits in our database. Do you want to continue?");
 if (r==true)
 {  
 var dataObj = {
    fname : document.getElementById('fname').value,                  
    phone : document.getElementById('phone').value,
    pemail : document.getElementById('email').value
}
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST","insert_details.php", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataObj));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState>3) {
        window.location = 'http://localhost/myproject/test.php?eid=<?php echo $primary_email; ?>';
    }
}

alert("test");



  }
else
  {
   window.location = 'http://localhost/myproject/registration_request.php'
   }

    </script>
```

code in insert_details.php

```
$date = "Date:" . date("d/m/Y h:i:s") . "\n"; //to get today's date and time                  
        $logfile = "testing";
         $fpath ="myproject/";
        $filepath = $fpath .$logfile . '-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv';  //path of error log file

        $fh1 = fopen($filepath, 'a') or die("can't open file"); //opening the error log file 
        fwrite($fh1, "******************index*******************" . "\n");
        fwrite($fh1, $date); 


$test=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
fwrite($fh1, $test[0]);
```

Comment: How are you accessing it in PHP? Since you're using JSON data, you can't use `$_POST` variables inside PHP. You'd have to use `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: yeah i am using the same line of code in insert_details.php page. but it is not working

Comment: "it is not working" is an extremely vague description. What happens when you `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`?

Comment: Sorry Colin. i put it as //$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); then i am trying to this $email = json_decode($_POST['pemail']);
mysql_query("UPDATE P_P SET First_Name='$fname',
  Updated_By='user',Updated_Date=Now() WHERE Email_Address_Primary='$email'"); is it fine?

Comment: No, not fine. By posting the data as JSON, you can no longer use `$_POST`. `$_POST` is auto-parsed by PHP when PHP sees an incoming request with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` value for the `Content-Type` header. Follow up with epascarello below

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending up a named pair. You are just sending up the value of the textbox.

what is looks like as a string.

```
xhr.send("myEmail@example.com");
```

Second you have a race condition between the Ajax call and the window.location.href.

You need to wait for the response to come back before doing the redirection.

Basic idea:

```
var dataObj = {
    fname : document.getElementById('fname').value,                  
    phone : document.getElementById('phone').value,
    pemail : document.getElementById('email').value
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState>=3) {
        window.location = 'http://localhost/myproject/test.php?eid=<?php echo $primary_email; ?>';
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
```

Comment: If he's using `json_decode` with `php://input` the named-pair theory should be a non-issue. But hah, I didn't even pay attention to the `window.location` assignment.

Comment: Then what should be the proper way of doing this?How to send it as named pair? i am novice in this. kindly help.

Comment: Thank you Epascarello. do i need to use this also xhr.open("POST","insert_details.php", true); where i need to send dataObj?

Comment: Yes, you still need all of that, I just put in the code that needed to change.

Comment: Still it is not working:( i have reposted my code in my question. it is neither going to insert_details.php nor to test.php page

Comment: I mistyped the variable name, I edited it. I had xmlhttp instead of xhr

Comment: I have made that change also. But it is still not working. Sorry i am irritating you repeatedly. can you go through the code i have edited in my question?

Comment: What is not working? What is saying in the JavaScript console? Are there errors?

Comment: i don't know how to check in Console but i have used alert msg.and it is not going inside xhr.readyState>=3

Comment: You do not know about F12 or Firebug? Learn about dev tools so it makes your life easier.

Comment: OO thanks. yeah i know and uses this. got confused with console. Thanks Epascarello & Colin